# Ansible best way to capture result from aws_s3 module if download failed and fall back to get_url?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to use aws_s3 module and if the download failed it will fall back to get_url to download from the web,
what I use to have is using block/rescue option but i feel there is much elegant way to do it
maybe capture the error of the aws_s3 command and based on this to decide what to do
how can I improve this?

```
- name: download
   block:
        local_action:
         module: aws_s3
         bucket: bucket_x
         object: "foo.zip"
         dest: "/home/home/foo.zip"
         mode: get
  rescue:

      get_url:
        url_username: "xxx"
        url_password: "xxx"
        dest: "/home/home/"
        url: "http://ftp.xx/foo.zip"
```

this is working but I'm not sure its the best way to implement this logic 
is there more elegant way to do it but not complex?
I thought about capturing the output of aws_s3 , but this can be changed over time .